# R interpreter missing in zeppeling docker image

Tags: r, docker, apache-zeppelin

I´m working with zeppeling notebook on a Docker container from the oficial apache image: https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/zeppelin

The issue is that I´m not finding the R interpreter there

[image]

If I try to import a R library I get an error saying that the interpreter is not available:

[image]

I´m not sure if can be installed from the working container, but that won´t be the best solution for this case since it would require to do it each time the container is started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is included, but it is not available as [default interpreter](https://zeppelin.apache.org/supported_interpreters.html). You need to call it `%spark.r` or `%r`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, R was included. Would you mind to provide the version of the docker image?

You can also build from the source from here: https://github.com/apache/zeppelin. At the very end of the Readme, there's way to build your own image.

Hope this works.